# Twitter Typehead, listing object arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter

I am having a problem using the Twitter Typehead with an object array.

please view the JSBin here http://jsbin.com/buyudaq/edit?html,js,console,output

Following is the serialised object array

```
var phoneNumbers = 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "phone": "+1 (923) 562-3211"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (924) 431-3216"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (932) 411-2223"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (857) 584-3623"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (914) 472-3779"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (876) 554-3637"
    },
    {
      "phone": "+1 (916) 537-3873"
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, Instead of passing a object, passing an array to 'local' option should do the work. 
Since your source is an array of object, it is better to specify which property value to show by adding 'display' option.

```
var phones = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('phone'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    identify: function(obj) { return obj.phone; },
    local: phoneNumbers.data });

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
 hint: true,
 highlight: true,
 minLength: 1 },{
 name: 'phones',
 source: phones,
 display: 'phone' });
```

Comment: Please describe how this fixes the problem, as it is very difficult for me to see what the actual change is.

Comment: "phoneNumbers.data" is the change